# One click confirm button of gmail schema not appearing inside body of email

Tags: gmail, schema.org, google-schemas

I have developed google app engine application to send schemas in gmail for one click action. I have followed tutorial at 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/reference/one-click-action

The confirm button is appearing in my inbox near the subject of email. But I want action button to appear inside body of an email (inside email contents when email is opened). Is there any way to do this. I tried different things like including Json-Ld script inside body of my message. Any tip on how to include action button inside email contents. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did u made it..? I can't even get button shown near the subject line http://stackoverflow.com/q/18651446/1306394 please help me. I am using the same email address in from and to field

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really need the functionality that you're asking for.

***For reference, if you wanted a button in your email body...***

The email that you're writing is HTML-based, which is why you can add the schema using HTML tags. Being that its a HTML email, if you want a button to appear in the body of the email, you just need to write your own button using HTML code.

***Regardless...***

I believe the action schemas are supposed to allow quick access to tasks attributed to the email subject matter. For example, if the email was an invitation to a birthday party, you could simply click the quick action in the subject line of gmail to say "Yes, I'm coming" rather than having to open the email and read it all.

By putting a button in the email body, you're requiring the user to open the email and read it. If they've done all this, then its hardily any effort for them to hit the Reply button and say "Yes, I'm coming". By having an action button in the email body, you're not actually saving any time or creating any benefit - they still need to do all the reading.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I do not want to add normal html button inside my email body. What I want is one click action button of gmail schema to appear inside email contents.

Comment: Agreed, and understood. Although it would be nice for consistency if nothing else, I don't think its something that would be that high on the list of implementation features, as it doesn't solve the fundamental purpose of the schemas which is to make it quicker and easier to deal with emails. Just my opinion.